# How do I request and process JSON with python?

Tags: python, json, httprequest

I am trying to send a GET request to a URL that I know returns data in the form of JSON using python.

I would like to know how to send this request to `http://someurl/path/to/json`, and how to parse it - preferably to a python dict.

Comment: may I kindly ask you to switch your accepted answer the one using requests?

Comment: Sure, that's how I'd do it today :)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

For anything with requests to URLs you might want to check out [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/). For JSON in particular:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
>>> r.json()
[{u'repository': {u'open_issues': 0, u'url': 'https://github.com/...
```

Comment: running it with `$ python GetJson.py` [doesn't give any response](https://github.com/iPrayag/pydown/blob/master/GetJson.py) but the same thing when run one by one on python CLI works fine.any mistake I did while putting it in a `.py`?(m a noob in python)

Comment: The problem I am having with this, is that DjangoRestFramework serializers are not accepting this as valid json, due to the 'u' prefix before the keys.

Comment: @PrayagUpd old one, and you probably found it out, but for anyone else wondering about it: in a `.py` file need to `print(r.json())` to see the response.

Answer (score 73):

Python's standard library has [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) and [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) modules.

```
import json
import urllib2

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://someurl/path/to/json'))
```

Comment: This is an old question, but I wanted to join webjunkie and point out that in 2012 the library Requests: HTTP for Humans is a potentially preferable answer.  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: You should definitely use requests.

Comment: But this is still useful if you are stuck in a benighted organization that makes it hard to load libraries that are not part of the standard library