# convert Python get requests to xml/json

Tags: json, xml, python-3.x

I am a network person trying to use python. I am trying to use rest api on one of the devices and use it through python 3 using the requests library.

```
url = 'https://erspan/api/?type=op&cmd=<show><system>'...not a complet url
rs = requests.get(url, verify=False)
print(rs.headers)
print(rs.text)
```

```
{'Date': 'Thu, 09 May 2019 21:34:39 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '1891', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'ETag':.....}


<response status="success"><result><system><hostname>erspan</hostname><ip-a.......
```

the object type for this is

```
print(type(rs))
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

I want to get this as json

Comment: Do you need to convert that XML into json as well? Then you need to parse it and convert it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I request and process JSON with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817481/how-do-i-request-and-process-json-with-python)